# No ethernet access on jetson nano with custom yocto image

Tags: yocto, ethernet, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I've created a very minimal image for the jetson nano with the recepe:

```
inherit core-image

inherit distro_features_check
REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "x11"

IMAGE_FEATURES += "package-management splash"

CORE_OS = "packagegroup-core-boot \
    packagegroup-core-x11 \
    packagegroup-xfce-base \
    kernel-modules \
"

WIFI_SUPPORT = " \
    ifupdown \
    dropbear\
    crda \
    iw \
"

DEV_SDK_INSTALL = " \
    opencv \
    opencv-samples \
    gstreamer1.0-omx-tegra \
    python-numpy \
    binutils \
    binutils-symlinks \
    coreutils \
    cpp \
    cpp-symlinks \
    diffutils \
    elfutils elfutils-binutils \
    file \
    g++ \
    g++-symlinks \
    gcc \
    gcc-symlinks \
    gdb \
    gdbserver \
    gettext \
    git \
    ldd \
    libstdc++ \
    libstdc++-dev \
    libtool \
    ltrace \
    make \
    pkgconfig \
    python3-modules \
    strace \
"

EXTRA_TOOLS_INSTALL = " \
    bzip2 \
    ethtool \
    findutils \
    grep \
    i2c-tools \
    iproute2 \
    iptables \
    less \
    lsof \
    nano \
    nmap \
    tcpdump \
    unzip \
    util-linux \
    wget \
    zip \
    curl \
"

IMAGE_INSTALL += " \
    ${CORE_OS} \
    ${DEV_SDK_INSTALL} \
    ${EXTRA_TOOLS_INSTALL} \
    ${WIFI_SUPPORT} \
"
```

To play around with a raspberry pi v2.1 camera. Everything works so far except ethernet access.
When I run

```
ifconfig
```

I get an IPv6 ip-address and everything is looking good (except I would also want a ipv4 address if but haven't looked into that yet). But when I run the command

```
ping google.com
```

Is says "ping: bad address 'google.com' and if I run ping on 8.8.8.8 it returns "ping: sendto: network is uncreachable".

It's not the ethernet cable or my router that has a problem, as the same ethernet cable and access works just fine on my PC. When the ethernet is connected to the jetson nano, the green light is constantly on while the orange light is constantly blinking.

What could be causing the problem and how do I fix it and get access to the internet again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the command:

```
ifup eth0
```

I got a ipv4 address and then everything worked.