# No internet access without running 'ifup eth0' or restarting /etc/init.d/networking on jetson nano with yocto/poky

Tags: networking, cron, yocto, init, ethernet

This is a continuation of [my other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970792/no-ethernet-access-on-jetson-nano-with-custom-yocto-image).

I need to *not* have to type in `ifup eth0` every time i boot to get an IP-address to access the internet. I've tried making a cronjob `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot ifup eth0
```

But it seems the cronjob is not even running even though if i edit it to run the command every minute.

I've also tried creating a init.d script (and made it executable with `chmod 755`) to run the command in /etc/init.d/ folder and made a symlink to the runlevel folder I'm running in.

Still, no internet access and no ip-address till i manually enter the command.

I also found out restarting the service with `/etc/init.d/networking restart` also does the trick.

In the `/etc/networking/interfaces` file, I have the usual:

```
...
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
...
```

If i set a static IP address, i obviously have an IP-address as after booting, but `ping google.com` returns "*bad address*".

So these are my questions:

1. Why isn't my init script working?
2. Why isn't my cronjob working?
3. Why do even need to run the command in the first place, as the `etc/init.d/networking` is running the `ifup -a`command?

I don't really care how i get internet access at boot time right now, i just need it to work. No matter what solution i come upon, does absolutly nothing. Everything is run as root, so it can't be anything about permissions.

Comment: Do you use systemd or sysvinit as init?

Comment: check whether this config is deployed: https://github.com/madisongh/meta-tegra/blob/master/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-conf/tegra/wired.network

Comment: I was pretty sure i was running systemd but i can see i didn't even add it (or any other init sytem) to DISTRO_FEATURES_append... so what init system am i running if i didn't specify anything? `ps -eaf` only shows init[5] as PID #1 - meanwhile I'm gonna create a new image with systemd in DISTRO_FEATURES_append and see if I can get it to work

Comment: You can check which init you use with `ls -l /sbin/init` on running machine, or in Yocto with `bitbake -e | grep ^VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager`

Comment: Ty @Nayfe. I'm using sysvinit in the system i have right now, i guess it is the default init. I am making a systemd image now however, as i am more experienced with that and because there is apperently some conf bb files from meta-tegra layer. I'll return once i boot up the new image and test internet connection.